# Running Android Marketplace Crawler ('hg' directory?)

Tags: android, version-control, mercurial, web-crawler

I'm having trouble figuring out how to run the Android Marketplace Crawler here: http://code.google.com/p/android-marketplace-crawler/

I think I just don't understand how the crawler is supposed to operate -- first of all, the source -- http://code.google.com/p/android-marketplace-crawler/source/checkout -- says I can create a local copy of the crawler with the command

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/android-marketplace-crawler/
```

How am I supposed to run this command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hg` command is a distributed version control system called [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/). You would first install the Mercurial command-line utility and then run the given command from your shell (Terminal on OS X). This would check out a copy of the source code for the `android-marketplace-crawler` to your current working directory.

Comment: Thank you! One more question, if you don't mind: The instructions also say to "run ant to build the program."

I'm assuming ANT is this: http://ant.apache.org/

The exact instructions say: Simply move directory hg/crawler/, which contains a build file. Run ant to build the program.

How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: If you have ant installed I would try to cd into the hg/crawler directory and run the `ant` command from your shell. If default ant target is set correctly that will build the project.